# Calculating percentile given z score

Tags: probability, statistics

What is the formula to convert a z-score to its appropriate percentile?
I have not found an answer on this site nor on Google. I assume there is a formula.

Comment: You mean... the area?

Comment: If $X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$, then for a certain quantile $q$ and the corresponding z-score $z$ will satisfy $q = \mu + \sigma z$. If you are interested in the CDF $\Pr\{X \leq q\}$ instead, you will need a numerical method to compute that integral - either pre-computed table or statistical software.

Answer (score 0):

If $z$ is the $z$-score, then you get the corresponding percentile $p_z$ by
$$ p_z =\left \lceil {P(Z \leq z)\cdot 100 } \right \rceil$$

Here $\left \lceil x \right \rceil$ is the ceiling function $\left \lceil x \right \rceil = \min \{p \in \mathbb{Z}| p \geq x \}$ and $Z \sim N(0,1)$.

For example, you may find $P(Z \leq z)$ here for $z = 1.2$ using [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=P(Z+%5Cleq+1.2),+Z+standard+normal) and obtain that this score belongs to the $89^{\mbox{th}}$ percentile.